# Random errors in communication via RFM12B

Tags: rf, c, microchip

I am using RFM12B as communication modem with PIC18F4550 on one board as Master board and RFM12B with PIC18F25K50 on two Slave boards. My communication is working but some day when I continue working I cannot receive data on Master board. I was monitoring communication via logic analyzer and Master board receives trash data. Communication is based on periodical sending same packet from Slave to Master. Did anyone had this problem? Suddenly it starts working and next day there is problem again. I tried to change modules, too.

Comment: Likley that other users of the same band of frequencies are interfering.

Comment: Yes, but communication string has preamble with 0xAA for frequency sync and after there is recognition packet 0x2D,0xA2 and after it starts interrupt for PIC and sends data via SPI. Everytime Slave sends data packet, it is recognized. It means it recognizes 0x2D,0xA2 but after these bytes is nonsense.

Comment: What is the probability that from time-to-time this occurs naturally - please think about this.

Comment: IoT network uses 868MHz as me, but it is not used much, around me is only WiFi and cell phones. Thats all...

Comment: You haven't thought about what I said.

Comment: I dont have idea...absolutely, it might be big probability because it is free for use band...

Comment: see my answer - it's not definitive but should give you an idea how non-robust radio transmission reception might be.

Comment: Yes, but I send same packet every 2 sec during 2 mins and there are only mess data received with no similarity. And suddenly after time it starts working. Does not make sense...

Answer (score 1):

The preamble might require two bytes of 0xAA to be recognized and thereafter, 0x2D,0xA2 is seen and this implies that a transmission is being sent. In other words, something like 24 bits of data have to be correct. You could also argue that this might be more like 30 bits if you take into account that there might be start and stop bits surrounding each byte.

So, with random bits arriving there might be a one in \$2^{30}\$ chance that the bits "match". That is a 1 in 1 billion chance approximately.

But you also have to consider that the receiver may only activate when there is sufficient power in a potential received transmission and this might be only 20% of the time.

This extends the probability of random noise/interference having "the right value" to 1 in 5 billion.

If the transmission bit rate is 10,000 bits per second (approximately corresponding with a receiver bandwidth of 10 kHz) then there is about 864 million bits in one day.

So maybe every 6 days you might get noise being recognized as a potential healthy transmission.

I've just thrown numbers together knowing virtually nothing about your system. For instance the air data rate might be a lot higher than 10 kbaud or the number of consecutive preamble bytes to be recognized might only be 1. You may indeed have other problems that cause this but never rule out the random factor.

Comment: My bit rate is around 9,5 kbps. To be correct my data packet is 0xAA,0xAA;0x2D,0xA2;0xA1,0xB2,0xC3,0xD4;CRC;CRC.
But behaving is not natural. It does not receive same data packet during 2 minutes and next day it receives every packet correctly. I would accept, that some packet is recognized some is not. But all data in packet are dummy not the last three/two or some in the middle.

Comment: Maybe you have a range problem which is the same as a fade problem or maybe some other stronger signal is defeating your true signal.